# How to transfer GET/POST data when using pagination Using Session in PHP

Tags: php, session

This is my code:

```
$tag1 = $_GET['tag1'];
$tag2 = $_GET['tag2'];

$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT name FROM info WHERE tag1='$tag1' OR tag2='$tag2' LIMIT $limit OFFSET $start");

// Pagination
while ($pagenumber != $totalpages) 
    {
    ++$pagenumber;

    echo "<a href='?page=".$pagenumber."'>".$pagenumber."</a>";  
    }
```

Everything is working fine, but when i go to any other page, I get this 2 errors:

```
Notice: Undefined index: tag1

Notice: Undefined index: tag2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass your get value into your link, be sure that vars are set before

try this please

```
echo "<a href='?page=".$pagenumber."&tag1=".$tag1."&tag2=".$tag2."'>".$pagenumber."</a>";
```